# Get Alpha Percentage of image Swift

Tags: swift, image, alpha, bitmapimage

I have function to calculate alpha of image. But I got crash for iPhone 5, work well with iPhone 6 and later.

```
private func alphaOnlyPersentage(img: UIImage) -> Float {

    let width = Int(img.size.width)
    let height = Int(img.size.height)

    let bitmapBytesPerRow = width
    let bitmapByteCount = bitmapBytesPerRow * height

    let pixelData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

    let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow,
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue).rawValue)!

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    context.clear(rect)
    context.draw(img.cgImage!, in: rect)

    var alphaOnlyPixels = 0

    for x in 0...Int(width) {
        for y in 0...Int(height) {

            if pixelData[y * width + x] == 0 {
               alphaOnlyPixels += 1
            }
        }
    }

    free(pixelData)

    return Float(alphaOnlyPixels) / Float(bitmapByteCount)
}
```

Please help me to fix! Thank you. Sorry I am newbie with iOS coding.

Comment: What kind of crash?

Comment: You are always iterating through all the pixels, therefore you need only `let alphaOnlyPixels = Array(pixelData.filter{ $0 == 0 }).count`

Comment: I got crash with EXC_BASS_ACCESS i captured screen shoot --> [link](http://imgur.com/a/QT3wk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `...` with `..<` otherwise you are accessing one row and one column too many.

Note the crash is random depending on how the memory is allocated and whether you have access to the bytes at the given address, which is outside of the chunk allocated for you.

Or replace the iteration by simpler:

```
for i in 0 ..< bitmapByteCount {
    if pixelData[i] == 0 {
        alphaOnlyPixels += 1
    }
}
```

You can also use `Data` to create your bytes, which will later simplify iteration:

```
var pixelData = Data(count: bitmapByteCount)

pixelData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
    let context = CGContext(data: bytes,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow,
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)!

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    context.clear(rect)
    context.draw(img.cgImage!, in: rect)
}

let alphaOnlyPixels = pixelData.filter { $0 == 0 }.count
```

Comment: let pixelData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount), so pixel data do not conform to protocol Sequence, not have filter :(

Comment: @Quyen You are right, my first fix will still work. I will update the second part of the question a bit.